# How do I order my plot by the values of my outcomes rather than sorting in alphabetical order?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Here's an example of what I am getting:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = c("David", "Bob", "Sue", "Mary"), 
                 y = c(1, 7, 8, 5))
ggplot(df, aes(x = y, y = x)) + geom_point()
```

The result is a plot that sorts the names of the individuals on the Y-axis in alphabetical order, with their x-axis values in random order. What I want is a plot that sorts by the x-axis values instead, with Sue at the top (value = 8), followed by Bob (value = 7), then Mary (value = 5) and David (value = 1) on the bottom.

The appearance of this plot is what I want, with the labels of the factors on the Y-axis and their actual values on the X-axis, as seen here.

How do I achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Use `ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(x, y), y = y)) + geom_point() + coord_flip()` When it comes to re-ordering geoms in ggplot, rearranging the levels of a factor is always the way to take care of it. `reorder()` allows you to change the orders of the levels of a factor easily.